# Clear multiple input[type=text] default values on button click before sending

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input

I have a form with a lot of fields and want to clear all the default values (unchanged ones) for the input[type=text] when I click the button preferably using jQuery. I am using the button rather than submit because I am will be using the same button to then submit the form to a local script and then on to a third part for processing. But my script doesn't seem to be working.

A simplified version of the form:

```
<form name="cpdonate" id="cpdonate" method="post" action="" >
  <input type="text" value="First Name" id="BillingFirstName" name="BillingFirstName" onFocus="clearField(this)" onBlur="setField(this)" />
  <input type="text" value="Last Name" id="BillingLastName" name="BillingLastName" onFocus="clearField(this)" onBlur="setField(this)" />
  <input type="hidden" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
  <button id="cpbutton">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and the script I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  // default values will live here
  var defaults = {};

  // Set the default value of each input
  $('input[type=text]').each(function(){
      defaults[$(this).attr('value')] = $(this).text();
  });

  // Functions to perform on click
  $('#cpbutton').click(function(){
      // clear unchanged values
      $('input[type=text]').each(function(){
        if (defaults[$(this).attr('value')] === $(this).text())
          $(this).text('');
      });
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: use .val() instead of .text() for getting/setting values of a textbox

Comment: Which browsers you want to support? You can use placeholder attribute for newer browsers (not supported below IE10 ) http://jsfiddle.net/h4hGP/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input` doesn't have text, it has value and you can't rely on the attribute once user changes it, need to get it from the value property. Also, your `defaults` object won't locate the value if it is changed.

Am going to store each value on the elements itself using `data()`

Use `val()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){


  // Set the default value of each input
  $('input[type=text]').each(function(){
     $(this).data('val', $(this).val());
  });

  // Functions to perform on click
  $('#cpbutton').click(function(){
      // clear unchanged values
      $('input[type=text]').each(function(){
        if ($(this).data('val') === $(this).val())
          $(this).val('');
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: Is there anyway to set the default value of each input only the first time? That way when the third party redirects back with an error I can repopulate the fields with post data and they will only have to make corrections not re-enter everything. Currently after the redirect it uses the new post data as the default and will clear that if unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/L2J6b/))

```
// clear unchanged values
$('input[type=text]').each(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == this.defaultValue) $(this).val('');
});
```

An `input type=text` has `.val()` jQuery method, not `text()` and use `this.defaultValue` to check the initial default value.

Answer (score 0):

You should use defaults[$(this).attr('name')] instead of defaults[$(this).attr('value')] because when user changes value then attribute "values" value also changes